# Replace a specific set of characters using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

I have an RTF string that contains `\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}`, it is used to indecate that the word that follows is misspelled (I think) and I need to remove it, when I do:

```
.replace(/{\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}/g, "")
```

I get two lines:

```
*
evtbl{Unknown;}}
```

When I change to:

```
.replace(/{\*\r|evtbl{Unknown;}}/g, "")
```

I get just the * and a second line. e.g.:

```
var tt = '\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}';
tt=tt.replace(/{\*\r|evtbl{Unknown;}}/g, "");
alert('"'+tt+'"');
```

I see:

```
"*
"
```

I could not find any reference about the use of the pipe `|` character so I need to know: if by using it am I asking to replace two separate strings one being `{\*\r` and the other being `evtbl{Unknown;}}` bottom line I need to replace the literal string `\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}` with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just a matter of escaping all the characters correctly

```
//sample string - NOTE: the backslashes had to be escaped for JS
var str = "RTF string that contains \\*\\revtbl{Unknown;}}, it is used to indecate that the word that follows is misspelled (I think) and I need to remove it, when I do:";

var regEx = /\\\*\\revtbl\{Unknown;\}\}/g;

console.log(str.replace(regEx, ''));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I do `tt = '\\*\\revtbl{Unknown;}}';` as you have done this works, however, the actual "literal" string is `\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}`.  The RTF is imported, not entered so I cannot change it - thanks.

Comment: Is the literal string hard coded into your JS as a string or is it coming from a variable? If the value is just hard coded as a string you have to escape the backslash. For example if you do: console.log('\\*\\revtbl{Unknown;}}') you will see that you aren't getting the double slashes

Comment: It's in a variable that is loaded from an xml file, so it is "literally", "exactly", "specifically" `\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}` - thanks.

Comment: It does not work, please show me how - thanks.  I have `t='{\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}'` how do I remove it - thanks.

Comment: Does that matter?  I have `t='{\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}'`, how do I remove it - thanks.

Comment: Yes. It matters a great deal. When you have a string in javascript that has something like \r in the text, that \r means a carriage return. It is similar to how if you have \n in a string it represents a new line. So, if you are trying to represent that string, you need to escape the slash (by preceding it with a slash) so that it isn't interpreted as a carriage return and instead is interpreted as a "\" followed by "r". To see what I mean, if you just console.log(t) you will see that the text that is output is: {*
evtbl{Unknown;}}.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that actually loads text off a server that has that string in it. Note the response is plain text, not JSON as JSON would require the same escaping of characters as if hardcoded in javascript. NOTE: This is using mockable.io to return the data, so it will only be working for 24 hours. It will stop working at about 9pm EST Dec 4, 2015: http://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/bgt1yL1y/

Comment: I absolutely understand, I will repeat:  I have `t='{\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}'` how do I remove it so that the variable t has nothing it it.  This is my original question and it remains my question - thanks.

Comment: If that is what the string is going to be when loaded from your file, then you would want to use: var regEx = /\{\*\revtbl\{Unknown;\}\}/g;

Comment: Thank you very much. Best regards, Peter